# Symfony Messenger component y redis transport: los mensajes se procesan en todas las colas

Tags: symfony, redis, symfony-messenger

Tengo 4 colas de mensajes que usan Redis como transport y se lanzan cada una en su respectivo worker (mediante *Supervisor*), pero cada vez que cae un mensaje en una de las colas, se procesa en todas. La documentación es clara al respecto explica que se debe configurar la variable de entorno `MESSENGER_CONSUMER_MESSAGE` en el worker para hacer la diferenciación de cuál mensaje se procesará en su respectiva cola.

> Nunca debe haber más de un comando messenger:consume ejecutándose con
> la misma combinación de flujo, grupo y consumidor, o los mensajes
> podrían terminar siendo manejados más de una vez.

La cuestión es que no logro dar con la solución. En el caso de doctrine como transporte es sencillo porque al configurar el nombre de la cola ya se logra diferenciar los mensajes.

```
#messenger.yaml:
framework:
    messenger:
        # Uncomment this (and the failed transport below) to send failed messages to this transport for later handling.
        failure_transport: failed
        transports:
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#transport-configuration
            async: 
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
            audit: 
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
                retry_strategy:
                    max_retries: 3
            async_backup_task:
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
                retry_strategy:
                    max_retries: 0
            failed: 
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
            sync: 'sync://'
        routing:
            Symfony\Component\Mercure\Update: async
            App\Message\UsuarioTraceMessage: audit
            App\Message\BackupDirectoryToRemoteStorageMessage: async_backup_task
```

Y este es el fichero de configuración de Supervisor:

```
    [program:squidmgr-messenger-async]
    environment=MESSENGER_CONSUMER_NAME=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
    command=php -d memory_limit=256M /var/www/html/squidmgr/bin/console messenger:consume async --time-limit=3600 --env=prod
    user=www-data
    numprocs=1
    startsecs=0
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
    process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
    stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/squidmgr_messenger_out.log
    stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/squidmgr_messenger_err.log
    
    [program:squidmgr-messenger-audit]
    environment=MESSENGER_CONSUMER_NAME=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
    command=php -d memory_limit=256M /var/www/html/squidmgr/bin/console messenger:consume audit --time-limit=3600 --env=prod
    user=www-data
    numprocs=1
    startsecs=0
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
    process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
    stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/squidmgr_messenger_out.log
    stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/squidmgr_messenger_err.log
    
    [program:squidmgr-messenger-backup-task]
    environment=MESSENGER_CONSUMER_NAME=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
    command=php -d memory_limit=256M /var/www/html/squidmgr/bin/console messenger:consume async_backup_task --time-limit=3600 --env=prod
    user=www-data
    numprocs=1
    startsecs=0
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
    process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
    stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/squidmgr_messenger_out.log
    stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/squidmgr_messenger_err.log
[program:squidmgr-messenger-failed]
environment=MESSENGER_CONSUMER_NAME=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php -d memory_limit=256M /var/www/html/squidmgr/bin/console messenger:consume failed --time-limit=3600 --env=prod
user=www-data
numprocs=1
startsecs=0
autostart=true
autorestart=true
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/squidmgr_messenger_out.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/squidmgr_messenger_err.log
```

Es posible que en el DSN de cada cola deba hacerse referencia a la variable de entorno que se establece en el worker, aunque no me queda claro.